Looking for 4 part book (bound as 1?) about a brother and sister w/ parents who are archaeologists
So I read this book in elementary school and middle school, it was never assigned. The copy I read was bound as 1 book, over 1k pages, for what I think were 4 parts (basically 4 books).
The brother and sister have parents that are archaeologists and it starts in Egypt or something where they’ve been there a while with their parents digging and eventually they find something that gets them on this hunt. The kids are trying to hunt for this “treasure” but the parents aren’t if I remember right, they’re just doing their own job and whatever they were supposed to be doing, the kids happened to find clues or something.
Anyway, they end up in India in another part and the major part I remember of that part is there is a large “pond” with a waterfall and elephants. They also end up in South America looking for some jade jaguar or something.
The ultimate reason for all of this is something about the moon, it’s some lunar treasure mythical thing. Not magic just special.

The Jake Atlas series? Or is that too recent?

If there is no magic or other fantastic elements, what qualifies this question for "Science Fiction & Fantasy"? (Personally, I find archaelogical adventure stories closely related to fantasy, but others here might not, and in any case, you would be better off asking the question in a childrens's books forum).
